# Is there a simple way to replace &lt; and &gt; with '<' and '>' in Doxygen HTML output?

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to read the standard XML summary blocks in my C# code. It works quite well, except for one issue. I have a custom Dictionary and in the documentation I have the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// The 'Add' event handler for an <see cref="EventedDictionary&lt;TKey, TValue&gt;"/>.
/// </summary>
```

Which appears as

`The 'Add' event handler for an EventedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.`

in Intellisense popups, as I expect. It does *not* work in the main HTML output of Doxygen, appearing instead as

`The 'Add' event handler for an EventedDictionary&lt;TKey, TValue&gt;.`

This causes no issues with Visual Studio, as it keeps Intellisense happy (thereby keeping me happy and I'm sure my successors on this project happy), but does cause issues in Doxygen's output HTML. Because of these issues, the HTML documentation is ugly. I am aware that Doxygen has filters for the input, but I cannot seem to figure them out. Maybe I'm just being too meticulous in my documentation...

**Is there a simple way to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<` and `>` in Doxygen HTML output?**

Limitations:

- I cannot *permanently* modify the .cs files.
- I do not have access to a program such as Cygwin, which would make this trivial. (I am running Windows 7, if it matters)
- Preferably, this can be done from within Doxygen's processing of the files, though it is not a must. I want to make sure it's simple for whoever takes over for me, so even a simple script would be fine.

The documentation looks like this in the HTML page:

## Detailed Description

Represents a standard Dictionary`&lt;TKey, TValue&gt;` type with events for the standard Add and Remove methods.

Template Parameters

    TKey    The type for dictionary keys.
    TValue  The type for dictionary values.

Definition at line 13 of file EventedDictionary.cs.

Comment: do the `XML Comments` show up at all in the code..? for example can you see `///` if so then can you not skip that or do a string.Replace on all line content that has the comments symbol..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not sure if I fully understand you. The XML comments are header blocks on the methods and properties, and the documentation uses them to create a short summary (naturally) of the method without having to show the code (it does this elsewhere, and parses it correctly when I hover over methods there, so I see the `EventedDictionary<...>` stuff in *that* part but not the summary, where it shows the escaped XML characters).

Comment: are you wanting to display `< >` tags then..? if so then do a string.Replace or use the IndexOf method.. if I am understanding you correctly

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I'm not running any code of my own to actually compile the documentation, just running doxygen from command line. I'll edit a better example into the question.

Comment: have you checked with their documentation / support.. sorry I misunderstood your question..

Comment: @DJKRAZE That's fine. I've looked through their documentation a fair bit and tried a fair few things on my end, maybe I've missed something.

Comment: I see what you have written under `Detailed Description` but that makes me think that you have access to the .cs Code or better yet do you have a method or code that you are currently calling for the working stuff..maybe you could create your own Interface to stub into the working code / framework that you are using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<see cref="EventedDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/>
```

See: [cref Attribute on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx)

Comment: Not quite what I wanted, as Doxygen reads the cref tag **exactly as is**. (It shows up now as "EventedDictionary{TKey, TValue}") I'll deal with it for now, however, as it is much better. Thanks.